# Using unity app how to read the asset in android SDCard?

Tags: assets, unityscript, unity-networking, unity

I am trying to read one file from my android sd card from my unity application, but its not reading.

using the asset bundle i have exported my file and kept in my android device sd card  and i am trying to fetch it and show into my scene.

Here is the code i have used for this:

```
public string URL;
public string URLAndroid = Application.persistentDataPath+/cube.unity3d;
public string AssetName;

private string path;

IEnumerator Start() {

    //path = System.IO.Path.Combine (Application.persistentDataPath, "/cube.unity3d");

    // Download the file from the URL. It will not be saved in the Cache
    using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(URLAndroid, 1)) {
        yield return www;

        if (www.error != null)
            throw new Exception("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);

        AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;

        if (AssetName == "")
            Instantiate(bundle.mainAsset);
        else
            Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset(AssetName));

        // Unload the AssetBundles compressed contents to conserve memory
        bundle.Unload(false);

    } // memory is freed from the web stream (www.Dispose() gets called implicitly)
}
```

Here i have used the URLAndroid as a normal downloading method and  ihave tried to fethch the model using system.io method but its not happening.
I have created the corresponding folder in my android device and kept my assets eventhough its not happening.

Plesae help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I have tried this all option but no use:

path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/cube.unity3d";

path = Application.persistentDataPath+"/cube.unity3d";

path = "/mnt/sdcard/cube.unity3d";

path = "/sdcard/cube.unity3d";

path = "/storage/sdcard0/cube.unity3d";

path = "/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.gh.Testing/files/cube.unity3d";

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I created pre-compilation script which will run before the compilation; this script will list the names of the files you want to access later in text file

```
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
 using UnityEditor.Build;
 using UnityEditor;
 using System.IO;

 public class BM_AndroidBuildPrepartion : IPreprocessBuild
 {
     public int callbackOrder { get { return 0; } }
     public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildTarget target, string path)
     {
         // Do the preprocessing here
         string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("Assets/Resources/Prefabs/alphabet", "*.prefab");
         System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Assets/StreamingAssets/");
         using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Assets/StreamingAssets/alphabet.txt", false))
         {

         foreach (string filename in fileEntries) {
                 sw.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename));
         }

         }
     }
 }
 #endif
```

then I read the text file and you can access the files in same way but you have to put them inside your project in Assets/StreamingAssets/

```
   #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string  path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/alphabet.txt";
          WWW wwwfile = new WWW(path);
          while (!wwwfile.isDone) { }
          var filepath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Application.persistentDataPath, "alphabet.t");
          File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, wwwfile.bytes);

          StreamReader wr = new StreamReader(filepath);
              string line;
              while ((line = wr.ReadLine()) != null)
              {
              //your code
              }
   #endif
```